# Date query in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

Any idea how to achieve the Date query in Hazelcast 3.2 ? I looked at the source code for 3.2 and I do not find anything. 
Is there something like a DatePredicate using which I can write queries like

> new DatePredicate("joiningDate > 1/1/2014 and joiningDate <
>   10/1/2014")

??
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use SqlPredicate with the following way :-

```
new SqlPredicate("joiningDate > "+joiningMinDate+" AND joiningDate < "+joiningMaxDate+" ").
```

Here `joiningMinDate` and `joiningMaxDate` are your values and `joiningDate` is the value in db.

Comment: Basically SqlPredicate expects the date to be in a particular format which Hazelcast expects which is EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy.
However I wrote a DatePredicate myself which can search based on date.

Answer (score 1):

If not wrong it should work using a SqlPredicate just as you wrote above.
Please see: com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicateTest::testSql_withDate

Answer (score 0):

why not write a custom predicate:

```
final Date fromDate = /*1/1/2014 date object*/;
final Date toDate = /*10/1/2014 date object*/;

map.values(new Predicate<Object, Date>() {

public boolean apply(Entry<Object, Date> entry) {

        Date date = entry.getValue();

        if(date.after(fromDate) && date.before(toDate))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
});
```